# Ruby - Unable to call win32-api

Tags: ruby, winapi, rubygems

I'm new to Ruby and am trying to write a small ruby script to call
win32-api

from scratch, here's what I've done

- installed Ruby 2.0 using the ruby installer
  (rubyinstaller-2.0.0-p0.exe)
- installed the associated devkit
  (DevKit-mingw64-32-4.7.2-20130224-1151-sfx.exe)
- ensure that both bin dirs are on PATH

Here's the error I see when I try to run the script

```
C:\Ruby\Ruby200\bin\ruby.exe -e
$stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift)
D:/kaira/src/ruby/main/myruby.rb

C:/Ruby/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in
`require': cannot load such file -- win32/api (LoadError)
  from
C:/Ruby/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in
`require'
  from D:/kaira/src/ruby/main/myruby.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  from -e:1:in `load'
  from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

I haven't posted the entire script here as I don't think its really important. The issue appears to be that I'm just missing / can't find the 'win32/api' gem that is required on my line 1.

Having googled this for a while, the stock recommendation is to
recompile the win32-api from source, which I did

```
gem uninstall win32-api
gem install win32-api --platform=ruby
```

This succeeded but didn't resolve the issue.

Originally I started with the 64 bit versions of Ruby 2.0/DevKit as I'm
running Window 7 64bit, although I have now switched to 32bit
Ruby2.0/DevKit, again no luck.

my installs are in
C:\Ruby\Ruby200
C:\Ruby\DevKit

my PATH starts with
PATH=C:\Ruby\Ruby200\bin;C:\Ruby\DevKit\bin; ...

Maybe I'm missing something obvious here, although I can't spot it. Any
help appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I bet it should be `win32api` instead of `win32-api`. So probably you just misspelling it.

Comment: This is not the case, and there is no gem called win32api